# openapi-generator (java) prevent suffixing enum with enum

Tags: java, openapi-generator

From a json model i generate java classes using openapi-generator gradle plugin 5.4.
Enums in json are renamed to Enum e.g.:
from

```
"BusinessCase": {
        "required": [
          "application",
          "lineOfBusiness",
          "productId",
          "relatedPartners",
          "status",
          "type"
        ],
        ...
          "lineOfBusiness": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "UV",
              "LV",
              "KV",
              "GEWERBE",
              "KFZ"
            ]
          },
          ...
        }
      }
```

it generates an inner class in BusinessCase:

```
@JsonAdapter(LineOfBusinessEnum.Adapter.class)
  public enum LineOfBusinessEnum {
    UV("UV"),
    
    LV("LV"),
    
    KV("KV"),
    
    GEWERBE("GEWERBE"),
    
    KFZ("KFZ");
 }
```

Is there a way to get just "LineOfBusiness?" ?

**Bonus** is there a way to generate enum in own classes?

(i don't have control over the given model)